# Problems with Anova because variable lengths differ

Tags: r, anova

Hey I would like to make an Anova Test with four different groups.
The problem is that I always get the same Error:

Error in model.frame.default(formula = fatalities$fatal ~ group1$fatal +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'group1$fatal')

I think there is a problem with the subsetting

Would be really grateful for help and sorry for my bad English

```
 `group1 <- fatalities[which(breath == 'yes' & jail =='no'),]
  group2 <- fatalities[which(breath == 'no' & jail =='yes'),]
  group3 <- fatalities[which(breath == 'yes' & jail =='yes'),]
  group4 <- fatalities[which(breath == 'no' & jail =='no'),]

  anova_mod <- aov(fatalities$fatal~ group1$fatal + group2$fatal + 
  group3$fatal + group4$fatal)
  summary(anova_mod)`
```

Comment: You might want to use instead `aov(fatal ~breath + jail, data = fatalities)`. You are defining groups of unequal size, aov need a dataframe and a formula on columns

Comment: Thanks with this I already made Anova with 4 different groups?

Comment: Yes it is done automatically, please check the help and examples online